# sql server giving error : is not a recognized function name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a backup of a database on sql server 200. I created a new database in sql server 2008 r2.

Now when i run a view i get the error :

```
'function_name' is not a recognized function name.
```

The function is there
And i can run it using

```
   SELECT [dbo].[function_name] (
   'hjh')
GO


 SELECT dbo.function_name('kjk')
```

Why would this problem occur when it is functioning correctly originally?

EDIT:

I think it may be a security issue as schemas owned by the user under dbo does not contain antyhing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure you are executing it in the correct database context.

If the view is in `Database2` and the function is in `Database1` then you will need to fully qualify the function using the three part name:

`Database1.dbo.[Function_Name]`

All objects in a view are assumed to be in the same database as the view unless  you specify otherwise.

Comment: @Beginner - can you be more specific?  What is like what?

Answer (score 3):

Is the view on the same database as the function? 
If they are not, you need to call it like `[database_name].dbo.[function_name]`